# unable to append CDATA to xml element content using xsl transform

Tags: xslt, bpel

I am using bpel composite, in the composite I use mediator component and in that I use xsl to transform incoming payload data to outbound payload. I have a requirement where I need to append  to one of the xml element in the outbound schema.
I tried using in .xsl file the follwing code:

```
<ns1:request>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="/imp1:error-event-payload/imp1:error-payload"/>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
      </ns1:request>
```

but this is not generating output as `<request><![CDATA somedata ]]> </request>` .
Is there any way where i can transform the xml elment with CDATA section.

Answer (score 1):

Well CDATA sections are a serialization option you can specify with

```
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="ns1:request"/>
```

That will only work if your XSLT processor or tool chain serializes the result tree to a file, not if a result tree (e.g. DOM tree or XPath/XSLT tree implementation) is passed on.

Comment: when i use xsl:output in my .xsl file, it says xsl:output is currently not supported

Comment: I am afraid I can't help with that problem then as I am not familiar with `bpel`, only with XSLT, maybe someone else will come along and tell you which options your environment offers.

Comment: is there any other alternative way where i can append CDATA to xml element content or any inbuild function like ora:toCDATA which will append CDATA section to content?